# Alert you must specify a value for this required field alert in newform.aspx

Tags: validation

I just added this code to trigger an alert on **newForm.aspx**. Unfortunately, after I applied this code Formula column Validation, my form is not working. Any solution?

Formula column validation is not working when below code was applied.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var alertSpan= $('span[role="alert"]');
alertSpan.text('My Custom Alert!');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the span selector's name? Are you getting an error during the code's execution? Does a hello world statement work during this page on document ready?